# How to throw a ball in an arc?

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

I am trying to throw a ball in an arc, either an arc going left or right.

Here is my code:

```
var gravity = 2;
this.velocity.y += gravity;
                _angle = 5;
                var theta:Number;
                switch(_direction) {
                    case "left":
                        theta = _angle * Math.PI/180;
                        this.velocity.x = Math.cos(theta) - Math.sin(theta);
                    break;

                    case "right":
                        theta = _angle * Math.PI/180;
                        this.velocity.x = Math.cos(theta) - Math.sin(theta)
                    break;
                }

                this.x += this.velocity.x;
                this.y += this.velocity.y;
```

It doesn't really look like the ball is "arcing" at all, it seems to be more of a diagonal line?

Comment: You need to add in a gravity constant that will apply to your velocity values. Also, you only need to set an angle when your ball is initially thrown.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code to reflect these suggestions, but it still seems to just move in a straight line (not a curve)?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it arc left for "left" and arc right for "right"?

Comment: Do I understand you're really asking about how to make a curve ball?

Comment: Also, how is this being viewed?  I assume a 2d view for lack of a Z-axis.  Is this a sidescroller, top-down, iso...?

Comment: A thrown ball has a parabolic trajectory, not a circular trajectory.

Comment: Right now you have a constant gravity modifier.  You will also need to increment gravity (say, by 1) so that each tick the ball "falls" a little faster--thus giving you not a straight line.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for...a parabolic trajectory! I know I'm using the circular formula, but what's the other formula??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When throwing you have two components.

1. A vertical acceleration due to the magics of gravity. This will be ay.
2. A horizontal component: Without air friction this is a constant velocity.

Let's say you throw the ball and at the moment of leaving your hand it has a velocity v0 = (v0x, v0y) and is at position p0. Then v0x will be constant for all time.

The speed of the ball at time t would be v(t) = (v0x, v0y + t * ay)

For each tick of your animation, add deltat * v(t) to the current position of the ball and you should be set.

Everytime the ball bounces, you should mirror its velocity vector on the surface it bounced and substract a certain *percentage* of its total energy (Ekin + Epot, although Epot will be 0 if it is on the ground and the gound is zero potential), in order to get a logarithmic bouncing.

If you want air friction too, just substract a certain small *percentage* of the total energy with every animation tick.

Here some code, not in ActionScript, but I hope readable. (The parameters to the ctor are both Vector2d; clone() used implicitly but you can guess what it does):

```
class Vector2d:
    def __init__ (x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def add (other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y

    def mulScalar (scalar):
        self.x *= scalar
        self.y *= scalar

    def mulVector (vector) # NOT the cross product
        self.x *= vector.x
        self.y *= vector.y

class BouncingBall:
    AGRAV = ? #gravitational acceleration (mg)
    DELTAT = ? #time between ticks
    ELASTICITY = ? Elasticity of ball/floor

    def __init__ (self, pos, v):
        self.pos = pos
        self.v = v

    def tick (self):
        deltapos = self.v.clone ()
        deltapos.mulScalar (DELTAT)
        self.pos.add (deltapos)
        if self.pos.y <= 0: #bounce
            self.pos.y = 0 #adjust ball to ground, you need to choose DELTAT small enough so nobody notices
            self.v.mulVector (1, -1) #mirror on floor
            self.v.mulScalar (ELASTICITY)
        self.v.add (0, AGRAV * DELTAT)
```

Comment: Depends on where his axes point. If it is on a monitor where y=0 is the top and y=100 is the bottom, the addition of a positive acceleration would be advised. Better let the acceleration vector point to the indicated direction and a sum will always work.

Comment: I think you meant to say "2. A horizontal component: without air friction, this is a constant"  The horizontal component of the acceleration is zero, and the horizontal component of the velocity is constant.

Comment: @all How do you spell "substract"?

Comment: @phoog. Sure, you got a = (0, -m*g) and v(t) = v0 + t * a. But I tried to express it a bit more simply. For that reason I didn't give the differential equation for p(t), but talked about animation ticks.

Comment: This sounds good but does the formula above mean the x position isn't really going to change over time? I am looking for an arc...

Comment: x Position does change over time. With each tick you add vx*deltat to it. x Velocity does not change. And as v = ds/dt, as long as v is not zero, there will be a change of s.

Comment: @redconservatory I added some simple sandbox code just for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

The equations are (V = velocity, t = time elapsed, x0, y0 = coordinates of launch point):

```
x = x0 + Vt * cos(angle)
y = y0 + Vt * sin(angle) - (g * t^2) / 2
                           -------------
                                  ^
                this is gravity effect, without this
                   the trajectory would be a line
```

You don't need to distinguish between left and right, for one direction V is positive, for the other V is negative.

Comment: I have found that using vector equations quickly accumulates rounding errors.  The component vector approach works much better.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things: (a disclaimer: I am not familiar with actionscript at all but I have made a couple games needing throwing arcs.)

First, cos and sin both have bounds between -1 and 1.  Generally x is plotted in pixels, so changing x by 0.5 isn't going to make a difference visibly.  Also, since x should be an int, it wouldn't even show.

Secondly, the computation power needed to compute this type of physics probably isn't necessary--maybe it is if you're doing an exact physics simulation.

Also consider Hyperboreus' second comment: horizontal is generally constant.  Thus, assuming that this is side-scroller-esque, you would need to vary the y component and not the x.